# Getting non enumerable object keys of defined object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I declare and then I try to get the keys of the object but for some reason, I am only seeing two keys show up and not sure what am I missing to get the keys I am expecting.

```js
studentModel: StudentInfo = new StudentInfo();
```

`StudentInfo` is Model defined as follows:

```
export default class StudentInfo extends HomeModel {

name: string;
address: string;
isActive: boolean = true;
}
```

Currently, when I try to get the object keys all I get is:

```
0: "customValidatorError"
1: "Component"
```

I tried `Object.keys(studentModel);` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(studentModel);`

I would like to get the list of keys to include: name, address and isActive.

I also did try this code based on a previous stack overflow answer and it does give me all the keys i am looking for but also A LOT more which i don't need:

```
 getAllPropertyNames (o //studentModel) {
        let propertyNames = []

        for (let proto = o; proto !== null; proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
            propertyNames = propertyNames.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto))
        }

        return propertyNames;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the actual code behind `StudentInfo`

Comment: Your code please.

Comment: This looks like a typescript class declaration, not a javascript one? And it seems you have never actually initialised those properties, so they just don't exist on your object.